# What supporting documents do I need for filing Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization) in the simplest situation?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork

Assume the following simple case: single (no divorce), no kids, employed and living in the US for >5 years, filed taxes each year, no citations/arrests/warrants, >5 years with green card, physical presence and continuous residence tests passed with no issues, answered no to all moral character/military/etc. questions.

What supporting documents, if any, do I need for filing Form N-400 (Application for Naturalization)  in that simple situation, aside from a photo of the green card? E.g., should I upload my tax transcripts?

Comment: While it is appreciated that you may find some parts of this process ambiguous - thus leading to the conisderable number of recent questions on the subject -, it is highly likely that if you followed the instructions literally, your application would be straightforward and correctly put together.

Comment: @littleadv the instructions don't necessarily mention what is recommended.

Comment: What do you mean "recommended"? Recommended by whom?

Comment: @littleadv by people with experience with the naturalization process.

Comment: I'm with such experience and I **strongly** recommend following the form instructions **to the letter**.

Comment: @littleadv I see. Which instruction recommend to bring tax transcripts to the interview?

Comment: See the link in my answer

Comment: @littleadv got it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should follow [the instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/n-400instr.pdf). The required list of documents to submit is (currently) on page 10.

In the situation you described the only required document is your green card.

Tax transcripts are not required, but are strongly suggested to bring to the interview.

Comment: Thanks, photographs are only required if living outside the US