# How does one get one's tax transcript for the 5th year for the US Naturalization process?

Tags: usa, citizenship, taxes, paperwork

It is [recommended](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/24076/164) to bring one's tax transcript for the past 5 years (or 3 years if naturalization via marriage) to the US naturalization interview. How does one get one's tax transcript for the 5th year for the US Naturalization process? https://www.irs.gov/individuals/get-transcript only has the past 4 years.

Comment: Shows last 5 years for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This IRS FAQ page](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/get-transcript-faqs) says:

> **Q5. How do I request a transcript for an older tax year when it's not available online?**
>
> Tax return and record of account transcripts are only available for the current tax year and three prior tax years when using Get Transcript Online. Note: There is a "show all +" expand button below the online tax account transcript type that may provide additional tax years you need. Otherwise, you must submit [Form 4506-T](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-4506-t) to request a transcript for a tax year not available.
>
> Tax return and tax account transcripts are also limited to the current and prior three tax years when using Get Transcript by Mail. To get older tax account transcripts,  submit [Form 4506-T](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-4506-t).

Thus, if the tax transcript you want isn't listed, and doesn't appear when the "show all +" expand button is toggled, submit Form 4506-T to request a transcript for a tax year not available.

As backup, you might bring with you an actual, physical copy of your US tax return for the year in question.